# Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2)

Tags: python, image-processing, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm building DNN to predict if the object is present in the image or not. My network has two hidden layers and the last layer looks like this:

```
  # Output layer
  W_fc2 = weight_variable([2048, 1])
  b_fc2 = bias_variable([1])

  y = tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2
```

Then I have placeholder for labels:

```
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], 'Output')
```

I run training in batches (therefore first argument in Output layer shape is None).

I use the following loss function:

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    y[:, :1], y_[:, :1], name='xentropy')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
predict_hand = tf.greater(y, 0.5)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.to_float(predict_hand), y_)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

But in runtime I got the following error:

> Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits
>   minus 1 (received 2).

I guess I should reshape labels layer, but not sure what it expects. I looked up in [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) and it says:

> logits: Unscaled log probabilities of rank r and shape [d_0, d_1, ...,
>   d_{r-2}, num_classes] and dtype float32 or float64. labels: Tensor of
>   shape [d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-2}] and dtype int32 or int64. Each entry in
>   labels must be an index in [0, num_classes).

If I have just single class, what my labels should look like (now it is just 0 or 1)? Any help appreciated

Comment: Why should > "A common use case is to have logits of shape [batch_size, num_classes] and labels of shape [batch_size]. But higher dimensions are supported." In many tutorials, including [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4&t=344s), the labels have size `[None,10]` and the logits have size `[None,10]` as well.

Comment: In that case, you should use tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits instead of tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Answer (score 9):

From the documentation* for `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`:

> "A common use case is to have logits of shape [batch_size,
>   num_classes] and labels of shape [batch_size]. But higher dimensions
>   are supported."

So I suppose your labels tensor should be of shape `[None]`. Note that a given tensor with shape `[None, 1]` or shape `[None]` will contain the same number of elements.

Example input with concrete dummy values:

```
>>> logits = np.array([[11, 22], [33, 44], [55, 66]])
>>> labels = np.array([1, 0, 1])
```

Where there's 3 examples in the mini-batch, the `logits` for the first example are 11 and 22 and there's 2 classes: 0 and 1.

*https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Comment: I've tried this, but then I got another error: Cannot feed value of shape (44,1) for Tensor u'Output:0', which has shape '(?,)'. Where 44 is my batch size.

Comment: I guess that means you're feeding a labels numpy array with shape (44,1) to the placeholder tensor with shape (?,). So try flattening the labels numpy array with labels.flatten(). This will turn (44,1) into (44,)

Answer (score 5):

The problem may be the activation function in your network. Use tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits instead of sparse_softmax. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

**In short, here is implements of it**

```
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=hypothesis,labels=tf.argmax(Y,1)))
```

[sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)

> *Computes sparse softmax cross entropy between logits and labels*.
>
> Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in
>   which the classes are **mutually exclusive** (each entry is in exactly
>   one class).
>
> *For example, each CIFAR-10 image is labeled with one and only one
>   label: an image can be a dog or a truck, but not both.*
>
> NOTE: For this operation, *the probability of a given label is
>   considered exclusive*.  That is, ***soft classes are not allowed***,
>   and the labels vector must provide *a single specific index* for the
>   true class for each row of logits (each minibatch entry).
>
> For *soft softmax classification* with a **probability distribution**
>   for each entry, see ***softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits***.
>
> WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax
>   on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the
>   output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.
>
> A common use case is to have logits of shape [batch_size, num_classes]
>   and labels of shape [batch_size]. But higher dimensions are supported.
>
> Note that to avoid confusion, it is required to pass only named
>   arguments to this function.

[softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2) and [softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)

> Computes softmax cross entropy between logits and labels. (deprecated)
>
> THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future version.
>
> Instructions for updating:
>
> Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow into
>   the labels input on backprop by default. Backpropagation will happen
>   only into logits.  To calculate a cross entropy loss that allows
>   backpropagation into both logits and labels,  see *softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2*
>
> Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in
>   which the classes are mutually exclusive (each entry is in exactly one
>   class).
>
> For example, each CIFAR-10 image is labeled with one and only one
>   label: an image can be a dog or a truck, but not both.

**here is the same implements of *softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2***

```
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
            logits=hypothesis,labels=Y))
```

Comment: why `tf.argmax(Y,1)` for lables I did not get the pont

Comment: in `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` we do not need to use one-hot encoded then I'm asking why to use the argmax btw Y and 1 here , why not offer Y directly?